# split RDD into individual component

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a RDD and want to split it into individual component something like key value as dictionary or individual list.

```
rdd=[Row(results=[Row(50th=u'1.00', 90th=u'1.890', 95th =u'6.00', 99th =u'4.00', Avg=u'0.108',  Count=u'112121')])]
```

Want to look like something below as

```
50th,1.00
90th,1.890
```

or key value as separate list like below

list 1:

```
50th
90th
```

list 2:

```
1.00
1.890
```

what i tired as below but I am getting only values not the key

```
rdd.map(lambda x:x[0][0]).collect()
rdd.map(lambda x: x.split()).collect()
```

but it doest help. New with pyspark, need some help here

Comment: Can you please share the correct code to create your `rdd`?

Comment: the rdd is created by reading a json file.. its  the json_file=spark.read.json(pathtojson) then converted to RDD rdd=json_file.rdd

Comment: That's great, but your code is still not reproducible.

Comment: the challenge is post the json read... with this particular rdd...  i have provided the rdd... so not able to understand issue with reproducibility... json file is huge so wont be able add it here

Comment: Just recreate your example `rdd` with `sc.parallelize([..])`.